# Apache : Request Out Limit

Tags: api, apache2, fpm

In apache server, there is any setting which is stands for **Request Out Limit**?

Example : I am requesting 1000 third party API call from my live server. It's taking too much time to get response. Same API call, I am trying from my local server and getting very quick response.

1. I have tried with making call using curl in both local and production server.
2. Restarted apache server.

Comment: Requests are going asynchronously? You are hitting limit at 1000, but 999, 500, 100, 10, etc. work?

Comment: No requests are not going asynchronously. No Its just 84 request which i am doing back to back. It's in foreach loop. @user3783243